# Problem Installing .Net Framework 4 Full on Windows 7 x64

Tags: windows-7, .net-framework

I'm trying to install Visual Studio C# 2010 Express, and it fails when installing .Net Framework 4.  The error in the log is:

> Installation failed with error code: (0x00003B01), "The resource loader cache doesn't have loaded MUI entry."

I've tried installing .Net Framework 4 using the standalone installer, but that also fails with the same error (at least it's consistent).  I've tried running the Microsoft .Net cleanup tool, but that doesn't help.  I've tried cleaning up the %temp% directory, but that also doesn't help.  I've tried Googling but it seems like I'm the only one who has this problem.

Interestingly enough, installing the Client Profile for .Net Framework 4 via Windows Update works (though uninstalling it doesn't help solve this problem).

Anyone have any ideas?

Comment: MUI refers to the multilingual user interface. Are you using a non-English version of Windows, or do you have non-English settings in the Regional and Language Options?

Comment: Hmm, I have an English version of Windows 7, and all the settings in the Regional and Language options (that I can see) are for English (Canada).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

OK, figured it out.  Turns out I was missing some critical system files (although I'm not sure how).  I ran the following:

**sfc /scannow**

which told me there were some errors it couldn't fix.  Then I ran the following command to scan the log (sfc will prefix actions it took with [SR]):

**findstr /c:"[SR]" %windir%\Logs\CBS\CBS.log >%userprofile%\Desktop\sfcdetails.txt**

The path at the end is where you want to save the output - in this case, I decided to put it on my desktop.

There were a couple of error messages related to two files: wvc.dll.mui and wusa.exe.mui.  Specifically, there were error messages that it couldn't reproject the files because they were corrupted.  They were in fact missing.  In order to fix it, I had to extract the files from the original Windows 7 DVD (I followed the instructions [here](http://www.sevenforums.com/tutorials/42776-extract-files-windows-7-installation-dvd.html) and copy them into C:\Windows\SysWOW64\en-US.

An interesting point is that even after fixing my .Net Framework 4 issues, running "sfc /scannow" still yielded the following messages about wvc.dll.mui and wusa.exe.mui:

---

`2011-04-24 15:52:34, Info                  CSI    000002e9 [SR] Cannot repair member file [l:22{11}]"wvc.dll.mui" of Microsoft-Windows-PerformanceToolsGui.Resources, Version = 6.1.7600.16385, pA = PROCESSOR_ARCHITECTURE_IA32_ON_WIN64 (10), Culture = [l:10{5}]"en-US", VersionScope = 1 nonSxS, PublicKeyToken = {l:8 b:31bf3856ad364e35}, Type neutral, TypeName neutral, PublicKey neutral in the store, file is missing`

`2011-04-24 15:52:34, Info                  CSI    000002ea [SR] Cannot repair member file [l:24{12}]"wusa.exe.mui" of Microsoft-Windows-WUSA.Resources, Version = 6.1.7600.16385, pA = PROCESSOR_ARCHITECTURE_INTEL (0), Culture = [l:10{5}]"en-US", VersionScope = 1 nonSxS, PublicKeyToken = {l:8 b:31bf3856ad364e35}, Type neutral, TypeName neutral, PublicKey neutral in the store, file is missing`

`2011-04-24 15:52:34, Info                  CSI    000002eb [SR] Cannot repair member file [l:24{12}]"wusa.exe.mui" of Microsoft-Windows-WUSA.Resources, Version = 6.1.7600.16385, pA = PROCESSOR_ARCHITECTURE_INTEL (0), Culture = [l:10{5}]"en-US", VersionScope = 1 nonSxS, PublicKeyToken = {l:8 b:31bf3856ad364e35}, Type neutral, TypeName neutral, PublicKey neutral in the store, file is missing`

`2011-04-24 15:52:34, Info                  CSI    000002ec [SR] This component was referenced by [l:266{133}]"Microsoft-Windows-WindowsFoundation-LanguagePack-Package~31bf3856ad364e35~amd64~en-US~6.1.7601.17514.Windows Foundation Language Pack"`

`2011-04-24 15:52:34, Info                  CSI    000002ed [SR] Cannot repair member file [l:22{11}]"wvc.dll.mui" of Microsoft-Windows-PerformanceToolsGui.Resources, Version = 6.1.7600.16385, pA = PROCESSOR_ARCHITECTURE_IA32_ON_WIN64 (10), Culture = [l:10{5}]"en-US", VersionScope = 1 nonSxS, PublicKeyToken = {l:8 b:31bf3856ad364e35}, Type neutral, TypeName neutral, PublicKey neutral in the store, file is missing`

`2011-04-24 15:52:34, Info                  CSI    000002ee [SR] This component was referenced by [l:266{133}]"Microsoft-Windows-WindowsFoundation-LanguagePack-Package~31bf3856ad364e35~amd64~en-US~6.1.7601.17514.Windows Foundation Language Pack"`

---

Although the ones about reprojecting were gone.  Not sure what to make of that.